# Overriding FOSUserBundle templates not working

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am following [the first method](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) for overriding templates discussed in the docs.

It is working on my development server, but for some reason it's not working on my production server (in any environment). The template file I created in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig` simply has no effect.

My dev server is windows and prod server is linux. It seems to me that it must be related to the install of the friendsofsymfony bundle itself. Why else would it not be picking up the template?

Comment: make sure all lower and upper cases match in Filesystem and Namespace, on Windows that doesn't really matter, on Linux it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was naming/namespaces, somewhere down the line.

Comment: Hmm, it's been a while. I think it was a lowercase/uppercase windows/linux thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.
Locally i work on OSX and remotely on linux. 
The path must be on linux app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/ not app/Resources/FosUserBundle/